# Clip-on Christmas Tree lights

Tags: batteries

I am making a prototype of a Clip-on Christmas tree light.  It has two lights with a 3v battery attached to the lights (because the lights are 3v) and a clip in the middle.  I need to find a smaller battery to make it more attractive and salable.  Can anyone tell me what the smallest battery I can use for these two lights would be.  P. S.  I am not an EE nor do I understand anything about electricity or electrical math, so please answer in very simple language.  Thank you.  I intend to market these to commercialization through a small business development center and I need to make a unit that is more presentable than a battery with electrical tape on it.  Any ideas on that would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Have you tried a smaller 3V battery?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is Coin Cell batteries. Of any type, with a battery holder.

What you don't want is an off the shelf battery holder. If this is a commercial product you probably want to make it look nice which means a custom injection molding enclosure for the battery and lights. Learn to use a CAD program or hire a mechanical or product engineer.

You also don't want to use coin cells, if you want to market this as a commercial product. You'll get just days of light out of it before the expensive battery needs to be replaced. There is a reason we still use wired Christmas lights everywhere. Batteries are inefficient

Answer (score 0):

Use the shiny surface of a [CR2032](http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/cr2032.pdf) (20mm diameter x 3.2mm thick) as a reflective backing or otherwise integrate it into your design.

You're not going to get much life out of a coin cell, even with premium performance LEDs, but that particular one is probably your best choice. At least the end user can buy replacements at a Dollar store.